# How to authorize the service layer of a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building an application that displays information from a database on a website. The application is secured using Spring Security and my users can have different roles. The records shall be displayed depending on the roles of the current user. For example I want to display books from a database. Role `X` can see only some books and role `Y`, too. But role `ADMIN` can see all books.

Now I wonder where and how the authorization happens. I thought the service layer would be a good place, but how can I query for books the roles of the current user have access to.

My tables look like this:

```
book (id, name)
role (id, name)
role_book (id, role_id, book_id)
```

Thus a query for the books would be `SELECT b.id, b.name FROM book b, role r role_book rb WHERE b.id = rb.book_id AND r.id = rb.role_id AND r.name IN (<roles of the current user>)`. When the current user has the `ADMIN` role I would simply select all books in the database.

But how do I execute these queries in a Spring service method? I think that this is a common authorization task. Are there any Spring mechanisms to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do a simple redesign which will also make the data layer more reusable. It would be like this.

**Service Layer**

Here we take the current user's roles and pass to the data layer.

```
Iterable<Book> findAllMyBooks(){
...
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()getAuthentication();
    for (GrantedAuthority auth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
        roles.add(auth.getAuthority());
    }
    bookRepository.findAllByRoles(roles);
...
}
```

**Data Layer**

Query for the Books based on roles. So you can use this to fetch books for non-logged in users later on in administration panels.

*Please note that I didn't had time to checked the JPQL query. There can be an error in the `'ADMIN' IN (:roles)`. Kindly check this.*

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b INNER JOIN b.roles r WHERE r.name IN (:roles) OR 'ADMIN' IN (:roles)")
Iterable<Book> findAllByRoles(@Param("roles") List<String> roles);
```

**Entity Model**

Map `Many to many` relationship with `Roles` and `Books`

Answer (score 1):

For method authorization you can for example use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`

annotation on top of method, here's a link on the subject:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

For checking the role of user you can also use

```
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.isUserInRole(String role)
```

in Spring Security 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security 4 has Spring Data integration now: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#data

In your Spring Data respository:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo,Long> {
    @Query("select f from Foo f where f.owner.id = ?#{ principal?.id }")
    Page<Foo> find(Pageable pageable);
}
```